# JavaFX: 1st ListCell in ListView not updating when programatically changed

Tags: javafx-8

I'm using Java 8u51. This is really odd. I update ListCells through the Observer pattern, doing the following:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
   cell.startEdit();
   PojoSample entry = (PojoSample) o;
   setName(entry.getName());
   cell.commitEdit(this);
}
```

While troubleshooting the issue, I commented out the Observer update, and used a for loop to iterate over the ListView items (btw, the items hold a reference to their ListCell, for convenience), doing the same thing above, which is to set the cell to editing, and commit the edit afterwards.

On both methods, the 1st item never gets updated, while the rest of the list has no problem updating, regardless of size. I can confirm it received the values properly, and that the cell actually holds the correct data; it's just not displaying like it should.

The only time I can change the 1st item, is to manually edit it. I edit a cell by using a custom TextField that becomes the ListCell's graphic, when the overridden startEdit() method is called.

Has anyone come across this? Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: "The items hold a reference to their `ListCell`". This almost certainly will not work. Cells are reused by the `ListView` and will change the item which they represent during their lifespan. Do you account for items that do not have a corresponding cell? If you think you have accounted for the way `ListCell`s are used, you'll need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for anyone to really be able to answer your question.

Comment: And I guess the bigger question is why you are trying to use `ListCell`s this way. JavaFX already implements the Observer pattern for you, so you are reinventing the wheel. Just override the `ListCell`'s `updateItem(...)` method: that method is already called automatically when the model changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments James_D. Sorry for the confusion, the cell reference was made for convenience of demonstrating the issue in the small code block above.

Comment: Ran out of edit time up there. continuing: I'll try to get that MCVE up as soon as I can. As for the bigger question, the application I'm working on is not purely JavaFX. There is an embedded / associated (separate window when not embedded) component made from JOGL, and I needed to notify the JavaFX UI about elements within this component. The ListView lists the names of the graphical elements that are created on the canvas.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do employ a custom cell factory, and have overridden the cell's updateItem, startEdit and cancelEdit methods. I did also find out that if I add another element to the list, the 1st item will then display the data it holds properly. If I make a hundred entries, the 99 that come after the first will update correctly, just not the first one. I have to reiterate that when commitItem() is called, the 1st cell does have the updated data, it's just not showing it unless a manual edit is done on the cell, or a new item is added to the list. weird.

Comment: OK, then why are you calling `startEdit(...)` and `commitEdit(...)`? Those are intended for user edits, not updates to the data. Why not just call `setText(...)` and/or `setGraphic(...)`? I guess you just need to create an MCVE.